# Show fetched data in a table using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I want to show data in a table using angularjs in codeigniter.

Controller:

```
 public function source_list_for_test(){
   $data['get_source'] = $this-> admin_model-> get_all_source_list_for_test();
   echo json_encode($data['get_source']);
 }
```

Model:

```
function get_all_source_list_for_test() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('source');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

View:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
 </script>
<div class="table-responsive" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="tabletest">
   <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Sl No.</th>                                   
           <th>Name</th>                                    
           <th>Action</th>               
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>                                    
        <tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
           <td>{{index + 1}}</td>                                        
           <td>{{data.name}}</td>                                        
           <td><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-fill" href="">
                 <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>    
               <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-edit btn-fill delete" id="" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
           </td>
        </tr>                                        
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>app/js_code.js></script>
```

Js file is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
   app.controller('tabletest', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get(baseUrl + "admin/source_list_for_test")
     .then(function(response) {
       $scope.datas = response.data;
     });
   });
 </script>
```

I tried this but data not fetched and not bind in my view page.this shows below screen shoot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38SiZ.png)

Comment: Is your webservice getting called ??

Comment: no not called it shows an error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: Can u do Plunker of your code ??

Comment: sorry i cant get

Comment: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) is a website where you can run js code.

Comment: May not even be data related. Your app is not bootstrapping properly or you wouldn't see the `{{}}` notation in the view. Use browser console to check errors

Comment: And when debugging, it's recommended to load the full angulajs file and not the minified version (For more descriptive errors in the console), so replace https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js with https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js

Answer (score 0):

did you check for app.js file, may be app.js not downloaded.